# numpy.i is missing. What is the recommended way to install it?

Tags: python, numpy, swig

I am writing a C++ library which can be called from both C++ and Python by using SWIG-Python interface. I would like to make a few functions in the library to return numpy array when they are used in Python.

The SWIG documentation [1] says that `numpy.i` located under `numpy/docs/swig` can be used for this purpose. But I cannot find this directory on the following systems.

- Scientific Linux 6.4 (RHEL 6.4 clone) + Python 2.6 + NumPy 1.4 (installed via `yum`)
- OS X Mavericks + Python 2.7 + NumPy 1.8 (via `easy_install`)
- OS X Mavericks + Python 2.7 + NumPy 1.8 (built from the source `python setup.py install`)

There exists `numpy.i` under `numpy-1.8.0/doc/swig` if I get the .tar.gz source code from the NumPy site. But this file is not automatically installed when `python setup.py install` is executed.

**So I would like to know what the best or recommended way to install `numpy.i` on my system is.**

As I distribute this library to my colleagues, putting `numpy.i` in my code might be an easy solution. But I am concerning about version mismatch with their NumPy.

[1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html

Comment: Are you sure you want SWIG instead of the newer and much more Pythonic Cython? (Just asking.)

Comment: @larsmans My colleagues and I have been using this library based on SWIG for a while, and thus using Cython is not my option.

Comment: @larsmans In addition, our final product will be used in C/C++ to maximize its speed. Python is currently used for quick test purposes only.

Comment: I'll buy the first reason, but for setting up quick tests, Cython is IME a lot easier than SWIG :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest option is probably just to bundle a copy of `numpy.i` with your project, as the file is not currently installed by Numpy itself.

The `numpy.i` file is written using Numpy's C-API, so the backward compatibility questions are the same as if you wrote the corresponding C code by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I included the latest `numpy.i` taken from NumPy 1.8.0 in my source code. It seems to be the best solution for the moment. I tested this `numpy.i` on the above two systems to find that it worked without any problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code snippet to your `setup.py` file to download `numpy.i` from [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) at build time:

```
import re
import requests
import numpy

np_version = re.compile(r'(?P<MAJOR>[0-9]+)\.'
                        '(?P<MINOR>[0-9]+)') \
                        .search(numpy.__version__)
np_version_string = np_version.group()
np_version_info = {key: int(value)
                   for key, value in np_version.groupdict().items()}

np_file_name = 'numpy.i'
np_file_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/maintenance/' + \
              np_version_string + '.x/tools/swig/' + np_file_name
if(np_version_info['MAJOR'] == 1 and np_version_info['MINOR'] < 9):
    np_file_url = np_file_url.replace('tools', 'doc')

chunk_size = 8196
with open(np_file_name, 'wb') as file:
    for chunk in requests.get(np_file_url,
                              stream=True).iter_content(chunk_size):
        file.write(chunk)
```

It downloads the suitable file depending on **Numpy**'s version and works in both Python 2 and 3 with [**requests library**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, similar to what was proposed by Alberto Marquez above, is to include a Makefile that automatically downloads the `numpy.i` file in case it is missing. Here is one example, cf. the line immediately below `${PROGRAM}:    ${PROGRAM}.c`:

```
# put here the root name of your code
PROGRAM = simple

CC  = gcc
CFLAGS  = -c -fPIC -O2  
LFLAGS  = -I/Users/nemmen/anaconda3/include/python3.5m -I/Users/nemmen/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${PROGRAM}.c
    [ -f ./numpy.i ] && echo "numpy.i already here, good" || wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/master/tools/swig/numpy.i

    swig -python -o ${PROGRAM}_wrap.c ${PROGRAM}.i
    $(CC) ${CFLAGS} ${PROGRAM}.c -o ${PROGRAM}.o
    $(CC) ${CFLAGS} ${PROGRAM}_wrap.c -o ${PROGRAM}_wrap.o ${LFLAGS}
    ld -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o _${PROGRAM}.so *.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod *.so ${PROGRAM}_wrap.c numpy.i __pycache__
```

For an example of where this Makefile is adopted, check out this [repo](https://github.com/rsnemmen/swig-numpy-2d).

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of numpy.i from this [GitHub page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/tools/swig/numpy.i) and put it in the local directory.